# Optimised Code for Pulling Taxonomy Posts

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query

I have created a CPT called 'stores', each store has a taxonomy registered to it called 'store-type' (i.e. whether it's a fashion store, or kids etc). There is a third taxonomy 'floor'. A store can be on multiple floors like a large department store.

I have been asked by the client to list all the 'stores' by 'store type' and on each floor.

So far I have an idea to create a horrible loop like: (only pseudo-code at the moment)

```
foreach storeLevel as level
{
   foreach storeType as type
   {
      get_posts_by_store_type() /* Note this would be a new WP_Query() */
      list_stores();
   }
}
```

As you can imagine, this would create hundreds of queries. There is also some custom fields on each post I need to pull through.

Could anyone point me in the direction of a better method to list posts by taxonomy?

edit: I have tested a similar bit of code on just listing the stores without going through each level and it's created around 80 queries and only a 5th of the stores have been added. :/

Answer (score 1):

Without spending too long thinking about this one I would imagine you could do it with one query.

```
$store_array = array();

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $store_type = // get term id, slug, name from store type taxonomy
    $store_floor = // get term id, slug, name from floor taxonomy
    $store_array[$store_type][$store_floor] = $post->ID;
endwhile;

// run a foreach on your $store_array
```

From there you could sequentially list your store types and sub-group by floors within it. Post ID will give you option to `get_the_title()` and `get_permalink()`.

If you needed more detail you could add another dimension to the array.